# Outer product, vectorial operation and loop - numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays of size 15 : A = [a_0, ... , a_14] and B = [b_0, ..., b_14]

**Goal:** obtain the array C of size 8 resulting from

C = [a_0] * [b_7, ..., b_14] + [a_2, a_3] * [b_3, b_4, b_5, b_6] + [a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6] * [b_2, b_3] + [a_7, ..., a_14] * [b_0]

where * is the outer product `np.outer`. Note that:

- each sub-array is of length 2^i for i between 0 and 3.
- from the outer product, we obtain two vectors of size (8) and two matrices of sizes (2, 4) and (4, 2). We suppose that we flatten immediately after the product, in order to be able to sum the four products and have at the end a long vector of size 8.

My implementation is the following:

```py
inds = [0, 1, 3, 7, 15]
C = np.zeros(8)
d = 4
for i in range(d):
    left = A[inds[i]:inds[i+1]]
    right = B[inds[d-i-1]:inds[d-i]]
    C += (left[:, None]*right[None, :]).ravel()  # same as np.outer(left, right).ravel()
```

**Question:** what is the fastest way to obtain `C` ? i.e. is there a way to avoid having this `for` loop to perform the summation ?

If not: what are my options ? code in C++ ? Cython ?

---

NB: this is to be generalized for loops of `range(L+1)` with `L` any integer. In the example above I have illustrated the case `L=3` for better comprehension. FYI, the generalized code would look like this:

```py
L = 3
inds = np.cumsum([2**k for k in range(0, L+1)])
inds = np.concatenate(([0], inds))
# Input arrays A and B are of size inds[-1]
C = np.zeros(2**L)
d = L+1
for i in range(d):
    left = A[inds[i]:inds[i+1]]
    right = B[inds[d-i-1]:inds[d-i]]
    C += (left[:, None]*right[None, :]).ravel()  # same as np.outer(left, right).ravel()
```

Comment: I didn't understand  why `inds = [0, 1, 3, 7, 15]`

Comment: I have added a NB at the end.

Comment: Since your `A` and `B` slices differ during the `i` iteration you can't do one whole-array slice and outer product.  But are there cases that have like sizes?  Can you group those?  `np.linspace` is a way of generating a 2d array of 'advanced indices'.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. And yes, I can group cases but this would only divide by two the number of iterations in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do:

```
C = np.outer(A[0], B[7:])+\
np.outer(A[[2,3]], B[[3,4,5,6]]).ravel()+\
np.outer(A[[3,4,5,6]], B[[2,3]]).ravel()+\
np.outer(A[7:], B[0]).ravel()
```

Am I wrong?

Comment: I have completed my question (see NB at the end). I hope it makes it clearer.